# Continuously Partially diff => continuously diff.?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if $f:N\to M$ ($N,M$ finite dimensional Banach-Spaces) in a neighborhood of $x$ has continuous partial derivatives, then $f$ is differentiable in $x$.

But does it also follow that $f$ is continuously differentiable in $x$?

Answer (score 1):

[It indeed does follow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions).  That is, $f$ is said to be $C^1$ at that point.